# iOS Simulator always shows 'x86_64' regardless of iPhone model being simulated

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, simulator

I'm using the iOS Simulator to test how my PhoneGap application behaves across devices (iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 6 etc).  I don't have each of these physical devices, so I'm limited to using the Simulator.

I can use PhoneGap's 'Device' plugin to get the model number, but in the Simulator it is listed as 'x86_64' every time, regardless of what device it is simulating.  (The one physical device that I do have, an iPhone 6, it is correctly listed as 'iPhone7,2' when the app is tested on the device.)

Is there a way to make the Simulator return the model number for the resolution I'm currently running?

Comment: The simulator is your computer. Your computer is an `x86_64`.

Comment: Can you use screen size to get the device?

Comment: Writing code that depends on the device is fragile - it will probably break when Apple releases the iPhone 7 or whatever.  Beyond screen size the simulator is not a valid test of how an app will behave on a device - only testing on the actual device will show that

Comment: @Paulw11 One does not want to do this only to write code to a device. There are use cases where you want to detect running in the iOS simulator versus on the standalone device. Why would you want to do this? Maybe because in the real iPhone device you are going to perform a barcode reader function but in the simulator that module will cause an error and you would like to emulate that function, to continue testing.

Comment: @Ric the correct way to do that is to check for access to the camera.  Simply because the app is running on a physical device doesn't mean that your app can access the camera; Access could be denied by the user or device policy.  If you check for camera access correctly then you should not get an error on the simulator or a real device.