# Ionic - detect that a device is an Ipad

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ipad

I tried to use the Ionic Platform module, but it fails to detect that an Ipad is in action.

```
constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
  ) {
  }
...
console.log(platform.platforms());
```

logs `iphone,ios,cordova,mobile,hybrid` so no help here.

Tried to check the user agent, it says iPhone, not iPad now. Also tried to use [this plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-istablet), returns false as well in at least the four different emulators I tested (Ipad pro, Ipad air 2...).

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Iphone type from simulator (IOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493800/how-to-get-the-iphone-type-from-simulator-ios)

Comment: @ceejayoz the question is about the detection with the Ionic Framework, not Swift

Answer (score 2):

Use `device.model` from `cordova-plugin-device`

Comment: It gives me `x86_64` as a model. That doesn't seem to be right for an Ipad :/

Comment: @JeremyBelolo Are you using an actual iPad, or the iPad Simulator?

Comment: The simulator, why it changes something?

Comment: @JeremyBelolo Yes, it definitely changes something. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641516/ios-simulator-always-shows-x86-64-regardless-of-iphone-model-being-simulated and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493800/how-to-get-the-iphone-type-from-simulator-ios

Comment: Yeah, simulator returns `x86_64`. But I've checked `navigator.userAgent` and I can see it contains `iPad` on it. Which simulator are you using?

Comment: Ipad pro 3rd Gen

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `device.model` from [cordova-plugin-device](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device).

Now, we know this will return you the model, but to further narrow down to individual models, you need to get an `Identifier` for each model from the list [here](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models). Once you have an `Identifier` you can apply basic conditions like below to get individual models.

**Example 1:** For iPhone X

```
if (device.model.includes('iPhone10,3') || device.model.includes('iPhone10,6')) {
  // custom logic for iPhone X
}
```

**Example 2:** For iPad mini (5th generation)

```
if (device.model.includes('iPad11,1') || device.model.includes('iPad11,2')) {
   // custom logic for iPad mini (5th generation)
}
```

**NOTE:** This might not work correctly if testing on a simulator.

Comment: Hum... Thanks, as I said on the other similar answer, yes it doesn't work correctly on a simulator. Vote for clarity of the answer though.

Comment: As mentioned, this solution does not work in simulators as all simulators returns `x86_64`. Just curious to know why you would need this to work on a simulator than on an actual device?

Comment: Oh, that's simple... I'm using a MacInCloud to build for Ios, using testFlight as needed to check how it behaves on an actual device but resorting to the local emulators for most of the work

Comment: @JeremyBelolo But, I assume that your final app runs on an actual device and the above solution will work.

Comment: Yes, the final app... Except that it was to workaround a bug that prevents me from submitting my app because Apple rejects it since it doesn't work on their emulators haha. Will try and find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following in your constructor:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    if (this.platform.is('ipad')) {
      console.log("Hey iPad!");
    }
});
```

Also, see the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/platform) for further reference.

Comment: This command returns false despite running on iPad